# Riemann–Liouville fractional integral from measure theoretic point of view

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, fractional-calculus

Does there exist a definition of the Riemann–Liouville fractional integral with respect to any general measure? Could there be perhaps a relation between the Riemann–Liouville fractional integral and the (fractional) Hausdorff measure that is studied somewhere? Any references to textbooks or papers are very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

Comment: Noted and done, thanks!